# Is number prime? (no recursion or loops)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given the following function:

```
def divides(n):
    def div(k):
        return n % k == 0
    return div
```

I need to determine if the inputted number is prime, but I cannot use any recurssions or loops. Does anyone know how to go about this?

I was told to use `sum`, `map`, and the `divides` function above, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

**EDIT:**

I've tried this, but I'm not sure how to input the `k` in `div`:

```
def prime(n):
    lst = range(1, n**.5)
    result = map(divides(n), lst)
    return result
```

**EDIT2:**

I am getting an answer, but they are all `False`. Any ideas?

```
def prime(n):
    lst = range(1,1+int(n**.5))
    result = map(divides(n), lst)
    return sum(result) == 0
```

Comment: Experiment a bit. What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: how many natural divisors does a prime have?

Comment: Hint 2: True = 1, False = 0

Comment: @JohnColeman I just put an edit to what I've tried, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: yes, you are in the right track, now use sum

Comment: Are you sure that `divides` function is what you have been given?

Comment: @timgeb The `divides` function works fine.

Comment: @Copperfield Where though? That's where I'm lost

Comment: @glibdud yes, but it looks so weird! But I guess figuring out how to use it is part of the exercise.

Comment: that map give a bunch true and false, and they act as the number I put in my hint went used as numbers

Comment: also range don't work with floats, so you have to change it to int use `range(1,1+int(n**.5))` the 1+ is to take in account perfect squares numbers

Comment: @Copperfield Well, almost got it working. See latest edit for issue

Comment: All numbers can be divided by 1.

Comment: 1 divides every number, so make it equal to 1 or range from 2 and make equal to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one liner version

```
def isPrime(n):
    return 0 == sum(map(divides(n),range(2,1+int(n**.5))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code that works for me:

```
def prime(n):
    lst = range(1, 1+int(n**.5))
    result = map(divides(n), lst)
    return sum(result) == 1
```